# Draftjs styling in React

Tags: css, reactjs, draftjs

I want to use draft.js in my project. It has its own css which I also need to import. In the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/docs/advanced-topics-issues-and-pitfalls.html#missing-draft-css) it is said:

> This CSS should be included when rendering the editor, as these styles
>   set defaults for text alignment, spacing, and other important
>   features.

1. How do I include the Draft.css while rendering the component? Do I include it in my main index.html?
2. Also how to give an `id` to the editor so that I can style it (eg. `border`, `padding`, `min-height`, etc)

Comment: Draft.css should be included in every page that has the DraftJS component. For styling the DraftJS in multiple places, inline styles can be used. If generic functionality is required, create a wrapper component on top of Editor and EditorState.

Comment: @Vijay Okay, thank you.

Comment: @Vijay How can you do inline styles? I tried `<Editor style={{backgroudColor: 'blue'}}></Editor>` to no avail.

Comment: I was hoping that the customStyleMap property would do it. documentation of that property is different from what I thought. I have upvoted your question.

Comment: Note that certain build setups (such as Create React App) automatically include the default css of the imported modules, so there is nothing to do in these cases.

Answer (score 29):

Depending on your setup, you should be able to include or import the Draft.css in the index.js file.

```
...
import 'draft-js/dist/Draft.css';
...
```

Answer (score 4):

draftjs produces Draft.css in the build and is available within the node_modules. Use the css for default styling.

For background color of the editor, the following CSS class should be modified:

```
.DraftEditor-editorContainer {
  background-color:#fff;
  border-left:.1px solid transparent;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1
}
```